# not using find twice when retrieving deeply nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am able to find the object in the javascript below but it is pretty horrible and I am doing the find twice.

I'd be interested in a better way and one that did not involve lodash which I am current not using.

```js
const statuses = [{
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'bar'
  }]
}, {
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'mook'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'none'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'soot'
  }]
}]

const selected = statuses.find(status => {
  const none = status.items.find(alert => {
    return alert.name === 'none';
  });

  return !!none;
});

console.log(selected)

const a = selected.items.find(s => s.name === 'none');

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Actually, you're using `.find()` three times. Once to go over `statuses`, then to determine if which `status` contains the needed item, finally to fetch that item from the extracted `status`. In fact, it's even more correct to say that you have three `.find()` statements, but you might end up with more than three executions of `.find`. In this case, it's actually four - you need to call `status.items.find()` twice as it's the second `status` that has the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested `some` and `find` like this. This way you can skip the the operation once a match is found.

```js
const statuses=[{items:[{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:5,name:'bar'}]},{items:[{id:1,name:'mook'},{id:2,name:'none'},{id:3,name:'soot'}]}];

let found;

statuses.some(a => {
  const s = a.items.find(i => i.name === "none");
  
  if (s) {
    found = s;
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
})

console.log(found)
```

You could do something like this using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). This is a bit slower but looks neater.

```js
const statuses=[{items:[{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:5,name:'bar'}]},{items:[{id:1,name:'mook'},{id:2,name:'none'},{id:3,name:'soot'}]}]

const found = [].concat(...statuses.map(a => a.items))
                .find(a => a.name === "none")

console.log(found)
```

Here's a [`jsperf`](https://jsperf.com/nested-find-vs-concat/7) comparing it with your code. The first one is the fastest.

Comment: You don't even need `statuses.find()` - `statuses.some()` is more correct in terms of intention, as you don't care about the return value of `.find()`, you just want to stop execution when the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all the status items into one array with `reduce()` and then you only have to `find()` once:

```js
const statuses = [{
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'bar'
  }]
}, {
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'mook'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'none'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'soot'
  }]
}]

const theNones = statuses
    .reduce(function(s, t) { return s.items.concat(t.items); })
    .find(function(i) { return i.name === 'none'; });

console.log(theNones);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

Note: `Array.prototype.flatMap` is in [Stage 3](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/) and not part of the language yet but ships in most environments today (including Babel).

```js
var arr = [{items:[{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:5,name:'bar'}]},{items:[{id:1,name:'mook'},{id:2,name:'none'},{id:3,name:'soot'}]}]

console.log(
  arr
  .flatMap(({ items }) => items)
  .find(({
    name
  }) => name === 'none')
)
```

We could polyfill the flatting with concating (via map + reduce):

```js
var arr = [{items:[{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:5,name:'bar'}]},{items:[{id:1,name:'mook'},{id:2,name:'none'},{id:3,name:'soot'}]}];

console.log(
  arr
  .map(({ items }) => items)
  .reduce((items1, items2) => items1.concat(items2))
  .find(({
    name
  }) => name === 'none')
)
```

You could also reduce the result:

```js
var arr = [{items:[{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:5,name:'bar'}]},{items:[{id:1,name:'mook'},{id:2,name:'none'},{id:3,name:'soot'}]}]

console.log(
  arr.reduce((result, {
      items
    }) =>
    result ? result : items.find(({
      name
    }) => name === 'none'), null)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One reduce function (one iteration over everything), that returns an array of any object matching the criteria:

```
const [firstOne, ...others] = statuses.reduce((found, group) => found.concat(group.items.filter(item => item.name === 'none')), [])
```

I used destructuring to mimic your `find` idea, as you seem chiefly interested in the first one you come across. Because this iterates only once over each item, it is better than the alternative answers in terms of performance, but if you are really concerned for performance, then a for loop is your best bet, as the return will short-circuit the function and give you your value:

```
const findFirstMatchByName = (name) => {
  for (let group of statuses) {
    for (let item of group.items) {
      if (item.name === name) {
        return item
      }
    }
  }
}

findFirstMatchByName('none')
```